# Why does ButtonBar ignore Background option and is it possible to color the actual face of the buttons in a ButtonBar?

Tags: color, options, button, background

Notice how I have `Background->color`  set in each `BUttonBar`but it is completely ignored. How do I fix this?

**Edit:**
(1) Bob Hanlon kindly answered my question.
(2) Is it possible to color the face of the buttons themselves in a `ButtonBar`?

```
Remove[barSave, frops, barops] ;

barops[width_Integer : 50] := {
   Method -> "Queued",
   BaseStyle -> {10, Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
   Alignment -> Center,
   ImageSize -> {Sequence@width, 20}
   };

frops = {
   ContentPadding -> False,
   FrameStyle -> Thin,
   FrameMargins -> 2
   };

barSave = Framed[ButtonBar[{
     "Save" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"],
     "SaveAs" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["SaveRename"],
     "AutoBak" :> AutoBackup["Save"],
     "Revert" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["Revert"]
     },
    Background -> Blue, barops[]], frops];


Echo[barSave, "barSave \[Rule] "];
```

Comment: FYI, 90% of the code is irrelevant but does a good job in deterring people from taking a look.

Comment: @Kuba please clarify. having difficulty deciphering your comment.

Comment: @JulesManson - Your issue and potential solutions could be addressed with a **minimal** example using a single bar or at most two. Anything more just provides unnecessary detail and complexity that tends to deter many from trying to help.

Comment: @Kuba you right, my bad. i am usually more careful but got a little sloppy due to working all night (no sleep) on this.. Regardless would you mind taking stab at it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

barops[width_Integer : 50] := {Method -> "Queued", 
   BaseStyle -> {10, Black, Bold, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, 
   Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {Sequence@width, 20}};

frops[bkgrdColor_ : None] = {ContentPadding -> False, 
   FrameStyle -> Thin, FrameMargins -> 2, Background -> bkgrdColor};

barSave = 
  Framed[
   ButtonBar[{"Save" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["Save"], 
     "SaveAs" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["SaveRename"], 
     "AutoBak" :> AutoBackup["Save"], 
     "Revert" :> FrontEndTokenExecute["Revert"]}, barops[]], 
   frops[Blue]];

Echo[barSave, "barSave \[Rule] "];
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it worked

Comment: is there a way to actually color the background face of the buttons themselves in a ButtonBar?